# Get hierarchy only for updated records

Tags: sql, oracle, select

i have couple of tables with some resource data

```
Resource
----------
rID |  rname | updatedstamp
R1    Res1      01-Jul-2015
R2    Res2      01-Jul-2015
R3    Res3      01-Jul-2015
R4    Res4      01-Jul-2015
R5    Res5      01-Jul-2015
R15   Res15      01-Aug-2015

ResourceTree
----------
parID | rID  | updatedStamp
---------------------------
NULL  R1       01-Jul-2015
R1    R2       01-Aug-2015
R2    R3       01-Jul-2015
R3    R4       01-Jul-2015  
R4    R5       01-Jul-2015
R14   R15      01-Jul-2015
```

I need a select query which will fetch all records updated on or after '01-Aug-2015'. Also, I need to fetch details of child resources of any parent updated on '01-Aug-2015'

so in my case, i need to fetch all records from resource table updated on 01-Aug-2015. In my case it would be only R15.
Additionally, it should also fetch details from the Resource_Tree table where any update has happened on or post 01-Aug-2015 . In my case it would be R2 R3 R4 R5.

Results

```
parid rid rname
R14   R15 Res15
R1    R2  Res2
R2    R3  Res3
R3    R4  Res4
R4    R5  Res5
```

Query tried so far

```
SELECT RT.ParID,R.ID,R.Rname
FROM RESOURCES R, RESOURCETREE RT
WHERE R.RID = RT.RID  
And (R.UpdatedStamp >= '01-Aug-2015' or RT.UpdatedStamp  >= '01-Aug-2015')
START WITH RT.ParID ='R1'  AND 
CONNECT BY PRIOR RT.RID=RT.ParID
```

Comment: I think it should be `CONNECT BY PRIOR RT.ParID = RT.RID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be an elegant solution;

```
with temp_tbl_1 as (
   -- get all the "rid" updatedstamp >= '01-Aug-2015' from both tables
  select rID
  from ResourceTree
  where updatedstamp >= '01-Aug-2015'
  union all
  select rid
  from Resource
  where updatedstamp >= '01-Aug-2015'
),
temp_tbl_2 as (
    select parID, rID
    from ResourceTree
    START WITH rID in (select distinct rID from temp_tbl_1)
    CONNECT BY PRIOR RID = ParID    
)
select t.parID, t.rID, r.rname 
from temp_tbl_2 t
join Resource r
on r.rID = t.rID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as (
select rid from ResourceTree
where updatedstamp >= '01-Aug-2015'
union
select rid from Resourc
where updatedstamp >= '01-Aug-2015'
)
select r.parid, r.rid, re.rname
from ResourceTree r 
left join x on r.parid = x.rid
left join Resourc re on re.rid = r.rid
where r.parid is not null
```

You select `rid` after 01-Aug-15 in the `cte` and then left join the other tables on ResourceTree table.

Comment: this is incorrect . if i have an entry 'R16', 'R17', '01-Jul-2015' in the Resource tree , your code breaks